# Is there a GEDCOM parser written in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, genealogy, gedcom

GEDCOM is a standard for exchanging genealogical data.

I've found parsers written in

- [C](http://gedcom-parse.sourceforge.net/)
- [perl](http://search.cpan.org/~pjcj/Gedcom-1.16/lib/Gedcom.pm)
- [Ruby](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz6.html)
- and even [Factor](http://paste.factorcode.org/paste?id=975)

but none so far written in Python. The closest I've come is the file [libgedcom.py](https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps/blob/21869e4939bbc347f3be2949c3a8fbc069361df9/gramps/plugins/lib/libgedcom.py) from the GRAMPS project, but that is so full of references to GRAMPS modules as to not be usable for me.

I just want a simple standalone GEDCOM parser library written in Python. Does this exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few years ago I wrote a simplistic GEDCOM to XML translator in Python as part of a [larger project](http://hewgill.com/journal/entries/277-genealogy). I found that dealing with the GEDCOM data in an XML format was much easier (especially when the next step involved XSLT).

I don't have the code online at the moment, so I've pasted the module into this message. This works for me; no guarantees. Hope this helps though.

```
import codecs, os, re, sys
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

fn = sys.argv[1]

ged = codecs.open(fn, encoding="cp437")
xml = codecs.open(fn+".xml", "w", "utf8")
xml.write("""<?xml version="1.0"?>\n""")
xml.write("<gedcom>")
sub = []
for s in ged:
    s = s.strip()
    m = re.match(r"(\d+) (@(\w+)@ )?(\w+)( (.*))?", s)
    if m is None:
        print "Error: unmatched line:", s
    level = int(m.group(1))
    id = m.group(3)
    tag = m.group(4)
    data = m.group(6)
    while len(sub) > level:
        xml.write("</%s>\n" % (sub[-1]))
        sub.pop()
    if level != len(sub):
        print "Error: unexpected level:", s
    sub += [tag]
    if id is not None:
        xml.write("<%s id=\"%s\">" % (tag, id))
    else:
        xml.write("<%s>" % (tag))
    if data is not None:
        m = re.match(r"@(\w+)@", data)
        if m:
            xml.write(m.group(1))
        elif tag == "NAME":
            m = re.match(r"(.*?)/(.*?)/$", data)
            if m:
                xml.write("<forename>%s</forename><surname>%s</surname>" % (escape(m.group(1).strip()), escape(m.group(2))))
            else:
                xml.write(escape(data))
        elif tag == "DATE":
            m = re.match(r"(((\d+)?\s+)?(\w+)?\s+)?(\d{3,})", data)
            if m:
                if m.group(3) is not None:
                    xml.write("<day>%s</day><month>%s</month><year>%s</year>" % (m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5)))
                elif m.group(4) is not None:
                    xml.write("<month>%s</month><year>%s</year>" % (m.group(4), m.group(5)))
                else:
                    xml.write("<year>%s</year>" % m.group(5))
            else:
                xml.write(escape(data))
        else:
            xml.write(escape(data))
while len(sub) > 0:
    xml.write("</%s>" % sub[-1])
    sub.pop()
xml.write("</gedcom>\n")
ged.close()
xml.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

I've taken code from mwhite's answer, extended it a bit (OK, more than just a bit) and posted at github: http://github.com/dijxtra/simplepyged. I take suggestions about what else to add :-)

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is pretty old, but I found it in my searches as well as this project https://github.com/madprime/python-gedcom/

The source is squeeky clean and very functional.

Answer (score 2):

A general-purpose GEDCOM parser in Python is linked from http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/cs460/2006w/assignments/program1.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) tool for including C libraries though the native language interface. You'll have to make calls against the C api from within Python, but the rest of your code can be Python only.

May sound a bit daunting, but once you get thing setup, using the two together won't be bad. There may be some quirks depending how the C library was written, but you'd have to deal with some no matter which option you used.

Comment: Or use ctypes or Cython (forked from Pyrex).

Answer (score 0):

Another basic parser for the GEDCOM 5.5 format: https://github.com/rootsdev/python-gedcom-parser

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution. Here, the question is asking for an off-site resource and is on its way to closure.